# How to calculate distance using coordinates from LocationManager

Tags: android, gps, android-sdk-2.1, android-2.2-froyo

I am using LocationManager to get the values of Latitude and Longitude of a user. These values are updated regularly to a database.

Now, i want to find out the distance between two users basing on the stored Latitude and Longitude values. I want to display a message when distance between two users is less than (say 100 meters). Can anyone please guide me with a tutorial or some sample code of how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the [Location](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/location/Location.html) class. You can set the longitude and latitude and there is a [distanceTo](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29) method that you can use

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I have also found a function here(http://android.voxisland.com/code_examples/How_to_calculate_the_distance_between_two_GPS_coordinates.rhtml)... I ll use both and find out which one might yield better accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Ou pode utilizar este metodo que eu desenvolvi...
Or you can use this method I developed...

```
public static Double distance(latitudeA, latitudeB, longitudeA, longitudeB) {
        double radius = 3958.75;
        double dlat = ToRadians(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(latitudeB))
                - Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(latitudeA)));
        double dlon = ToRadians(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(longitudeB))
                - Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(longitudeA)));
        double a = Math.sin(dlat / 2)
                * Math.sin(dlat / 2)
                + Math.cos(ToRadians(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(latitudeA))))
                * Math.cos(ToRadians(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(latitudeB)))) * Math.sin(dlon / 2)
                * Math.sin(dlon / 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        Double d = radius * c;
        double meterConversion = 1609.00;
        return d * meterConversion;
    }

    private static double ToRadians(double degrees) {
        double radians = degrees * 3.1415926535897932385 / 180;
        return radians;
    }
```

Comment: Math.toRadians(degrees) could be more accurate. Not sure