# Calculate distance of a building from Mobile

Tags: android, augmented-reality

Actually i want to calculate the distance of the building shown in the Camera view in Android using Augmented Reality?
I have the GPS coordinates of the mobile.

Comment: Are you asking about how to get the coordinates of the building, or finding the distance between two sets of coordinates, or both?

Comment: You can't get it until you have coordinates of that building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information on finding the distance between two sets of coordinates, take a look at [How to calculate distance using coordinates from LocationManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544972/how-to-calculate-distance-using-coordinates-from-locationmanager)

Comment: Thank you for this . but I have GPS coordinates of only one location i.e mobile not the buildings location. Can you suggest me some thing els.